# jquery stop slider at first child and last child

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery Slider, it slides across quite nicely. However I want the slider to not slide left if it has reached the first child and not to slide right if it has reached the last child

Ive tried adding this on top of the script I have but it doesn't seem to effect anything:

```
$('.yearslist').find('.li:last-child').stop(true, true);
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMR2Y/) or view my JS below:

js/js.js

```
$(document).ready (Initialize);

function Initialize(){
    InitList();
}

var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;

var left = function() {
    if (moveLeft)

        $(".yearslist").animate({ "marginLeft": "-=5px" }, 50, 'linear', left);
                    $('.yearslist').find('li:first-child').stop(true, true);


};

var right = function() {
    if(moveRight)

        $(".yearslist").animate({ "marginLeft": "+=5px" }, 50, 'linear', right);
                                $('.yearslist').find('.li:last-child').stop(true, true);


};

function InitList() {
    $("span#NavigateForward").hover(
        function() { moveLeft=true; left(); },
        function() { moveLeft=false; }
    );
    $("span#NavigateBackward").hover(
        function() { moveRight=true; right(); },
        function() { moveRight=false; }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
if ($('.yearslist').find('li:last-child').offset().left < $('#years').width() - 120) {
    moveLeft = false;
}
```

and

```
if ($('.yearslist').find('li:first-child').offset().left > 86) {
    moveRight = false;
}
```

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz4Sc/)**.

You'll have to adjust values 120 and 86 in order to make it wrap as you wish (or create variables).
It is not the best solution, but for what you have already done, I see no other solution.
Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks that worked wonders, had to adjust the figures slightly but worked like a charm!